# Bootstrap V3: grid system can't put two divs into one row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>OptimisedForum</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Bootstrap/setup/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script src='../Bootstrap/setup/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
        <script src='../Bootstrap/setup/js/bootstrap.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <form class="form-horizontal">               
                <div clas="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12" style="background: #999;">
                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="comment here" rows = 5></textarea>
                    </div>         
              <div class="col-sm-4" style="background: yellow">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="username"/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-8" style="background: red">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
              </div>
             </div>
         </form>
         <div class="col-sm-12" style="background: #123">
          <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
     <ul class="pagination">
         <li class="page-item">
          <a href="#" aria-label="Previous" class="page-link">
          <span aria-hidden= "true">&laquo;</span>
          </a>
         </li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
         <li class="page-item">
             <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
             </a>
         </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

As the picture shows, it is supposed that the 'submit' button can be on the same row with the 'username' input by the grid system but appearently it can't be anyway. I have tried many ways to do it such as putting these two divs into one '.row' etc but never work. So, I may need your guys' help. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You didn't have bootstrap included (maybe you did, but you didn't in the snippet since you included it from a local file).
2. You had `col-sm-4` which means at the small breakpoint, it will apply. Of course, this screen is the big breakpoint. To make them on the same line, just remove the `-sm` (make it `col-4`). I fixed that in the snippet for you.
3. You should always have the structure `.container > .row > .col` You skippet the `.row`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>OptimisedForum</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Bootstrap/setup/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src='../Bootstrap/setup/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
  <script src='../Bootstrap/setup/js/bootstrap.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div clas="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12" style="background: #999;">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="comment here" rows=5></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4" style="background: yellow;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="username" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-8" style="background: red;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="col-12" style="background: #123">
      <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li class="page-item">
            <a href="#" aria-label="Previous" class="page-link">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
          <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thx! It has been bothering me all the time until just now.

Comment: @wangted Your welcome. I'm always glad to help. Good luck with your project!